# Javascript AzureAd Consume Rest Service

Tags: javascript, azure, rest, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

**RestAPI**: I have a Rest API running Asp Core with AzureAd Authentication.

**WebApp**: I have a separate WebApplication running Asp Core as backend, with Javascript frontend.

*The WebApp backend authenticates through AzureAd, and then against the RestAPI to check if a user is registred.*

I want the javascript client to be able to consume the Rest API directly. How should i go about this without exposing the accesstoken?

I could go about sending the request from Javascript to WebApp Backend -> Rest API. But i really want to avoid this, because of unnecessary code.

Comment: You can use [ADAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)  which helps you to use Azure AD for handling authentication in your single page applications. and retire tokens for accessing your protected web api .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, you can try to implement [ADAL for js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) in your JS client. Leveraging `**adal**` to gain the authentication token, and when you call your Web Api, it will add the authentication header in HTTP requests.

E.G.

Suppose we want to call the Microsoft Graph API from our JS client.we develop a node.js script that uses request to call the Microsoft Graph API for groups to create a new Security Group.

The following code shows how the API is consumed from that script. Note that the token and the name are passed by parameter. Additionally, this function returns a Promise that is successfully resolved when the group is correctly created and rejected when is not.

```
var request = require('request');

function createGroup(token, name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "displayName": name,
        "mailEnabled": false,
        "securityEnabled": true
      })
    };

    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      const result = JSON.parse(body);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 204) {
        resolve(result.value);
      } else {
        reject(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

In order to call Microsoft Graph API, we needed to be authenticated and that is why in the previous section we have a token as a parameter of the function which was used to perform the request.

we should add the following code to generate the token. Note that we are using the adal npm package to do this easier, calling the acquireTokenWithClientCredentials method of the AuthenticationContext object. Additionally, we have some constants that need to be updated with the client id and secret obtained before as well as the tenant name.

```
var adal = require('adal-node');

const TENANT = "{tenant-name-here}.onmicrosoft.com";
const CLIENT_ID = "{Application-id-here}";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "{Application-key-here}";

function getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const authContext = new adal.AuthenticationContext(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT}`);
    authContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(GRAPH_URL, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, (err, tokenRes) => {
      if (err) { reject(err); }
      resolve(tokenRes.accessToken);
    });
  });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i will take a look into this.

Comment: Glad to know it helped please accept as an answer as it will help others who have the same ask.